# Access Form Prompting a for User Name

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, prompt

I have built a form in access that allows users to enter in their hours worked by activity (i.e. transactional processing, project time, vacation etc.). Current the form has a field for user name, start date, end date, activity and hours spent. There user name and activity fields are both combo boxes. The user name field has almost 60 different user names.

Is there a way to have this form in such a way that when it is opened up by a user, a prompt automatically appears to ask for user name? Than once the user name is entered, all records entered through this form have the user name already populated (unless the form is closed and reopened again)?

It would help if the user is able to toggle records "Previous Record" and "Next Record" after having the form know to filter by the user name selected when the form is opened.

Comment: If you are working with a secured database, you don't need to prompt them for a username.  Instead just use `CurrentUser()` to get their username.

Comment: See http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0008.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code you can prompt the user for the user name.  Then set the control you want to have that value in the **On Current** event:

```
Option Compare Database
Dim UserName As String

Private Sub Form_Current()
  txtUsername = UserName
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  UserName = ""
  Do While VBA.Strings.Len(UserName & "") = 0
    UserName = InputBox("What is your user name?", "USER NAME")
  Loop
End Sub
```

You may want to set the user name after the first field is entered instead of during the **On Current** event.  That way you won't have any issues with saving a record that the user hasn't entered yet.

Comment: is there any way to have the prompt use a combo box? i.e. the user picks their name from a list of names?

Comment: That's a different question @JT2013. Please start a new thread with exactly what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what isn't working.

Comment: @overmind i just asked the question. Hopefully a bit more clearly!